Game maker - when changing rooms in-game the character instead of going to the other room, duplicates and breaks
So, I'm new to Game maker, and while trying to make an object that teleports the player to the next room, instead it teleports the player a bit to the left inside another object and the character duplicates out of bounds, stuck there without being able to walk
I was just trying to make a room changing object
or door

Show your code in text form.

If you want to keep the player object through different rooms, then you should check that object to be persistent.
Doing so means that you need to remove the player objects in all rooms, except the starting room, else it'll either get replaced, or duplicated. The position of the player object may also need to be adjusted when changing rooms.

the thing is, i have the persistent option activated and i wrote the coordinates of where the player should go, but it either does that, or when the game is started you spawn directly in the other room

I recommend debugging (setting a breakpoint) the part when the game handles the room warping. That way, you'll know when it'll activate, and if it activates unintentionally.
